# how can we assign varchar variable value to postgres ltree column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

If we create a table tbl like below:

```
create table tbl(
    col1 varchar,
    col2 ltree)
```

how can we update col2 with col1 value whenever there is an insert for col1?
below function is throwing error at CAST?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_col2() 
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$ DECLARE
    col11 varchar;
    new_lable_path ltree;
BEGIN
col11 = new.col1;
perform replace(col11, '/', '.');
select CAST(col11 as ltree);
new_lable_path = col11;
    UPDATE tbl SET col2 = new_lable_path WHERE tbl.col1 = new.col1;
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END; 
 $BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
 CREATE TRIGGER insert_col2 AFTER INSERT ON tbl
     FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_col2();
```

Error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at position 4
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function insert_col2() line 8 at assignment
```

Comment: Which version of postgres do you use? Didnt `text2ltree(text)` help?

Comment: hi slavoo, thanks, I am using postgres 9.3

Comment: Thanks clement89, I dont know if i used it correctly in my function but it dint help, I got the solution though, as can see below,thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues in your function and in general it can all be an awful lot simpler, relying on automatic casting:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_col2() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    NEW.col2 = replace(NEW.col1, '/', '.');
    RETURN NEW;
END; 
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER insert_col2 BEFORE INSERT ON tbl
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_col2();
```

You must **always** `RETURN NEW` from an `INSERT` trigger that concludes successfully. No `RETURN` statement will throw an error and `RETURN` without a qualifier will cancel the insert. Note also that the trigger is fired `BEFORE` so that the `col2` column is properly set.

Every function is an implicit transaction block and an explicit `COMMIT` is not required.

I would suggest that you read up on the section on triggers in the plpgsql documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot Patrick it works, I am sorry for clumsy code, as you can see I am new to postgres and porting some MSSQL scripts to postgres, thanks very much for the corrections.

Comment: @RAFIQ: Really do read up on plpgsql triggers. They are quite powerful, especially if you want to work through views (use INSTEAD OF ... triggers), much better than in MSSQL or mySQL. And welcome to PostgreSQL!

Comment: I am sorry i misunderstood your last line and was thinking create trigger docs which i already did, thanks again i will surely read plpgsql triggers, pleasure to work with postgres!!